# Adding a onclick event to a code generated html element via object initializer

Tags: c#

I would like to be able to add a click event to a entity generated in the code behind.  Currently I'm doing it like this:

```
 TableRow row = new TableRow();
 row.Attributes.Add("onclick", "clickFunction(this)");
```

Is there a way to do this using the object initializer?  I am doing a lot of control creation/initialization and if it matched the rest of the code it would be nice

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No.  Unfortunately, the [Attributes](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.webcontrol.attributes.aspx) property only providers a getter.  This means you cannot "set" it using an object initializer- only retrieve it.  Object initializers only work with properties which provide a setter.

Your current code is probably the best option.

Answer (score 1):

No you cannot. It would be an option to create extension property, but they were not added to c#.